# Using Powershell scipt following json will show on CSV

Tags: powershell

JSON

```
{
    "members":  [
                    {
                        "id":  "4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d",
                        "user":  "@{subjectKind=user; metaType=member; domain=2161a74d-1c3e-4d34-a8c8-131360d2e92c; principalName=abc@my.com; mailAddress=abc.xyz@my.com; origin=aad; originId=bc20990e-cf30-4c37-9e4b-b04e37ab2b04; displayName=ABC; }",
                        "accessLevel":  "@{licensingSource=account; accountLicenseType=express; msdnLicenseType=none; licenseDisplayName=Basic; status=active; statusMessage=; assignmentSource=unknown}",
                        "lastAccessedDate":  "2019-05-23T05:54:25.14Z",
                        "dateCreated":  "2019-05-23T05:54:21.6Z",
                        "projectEntitlements":  "",
                        "extensions":  "",
                        "groupAssignments":  ""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":  "4c07118c-8dc0-4e85-97a5-5501003d620d",
                        "user":  "@{subjectKind=user; domain=2161a74d-1c3e-4d34-a8c8-131360d2e92c; principalName=xyz@gmail.com; mailAddress=xyz@gmail.com; origin=aad; originId=; displayName=xyz}",
                        "accessLevel":  "@{licensingSource=account; accountLicenseType=stakeholder; msdnLicenseType=none; licenseDisplayName=Stakeholder; status=pending; statusMessage=; assignmentSource=unknown}",
                        "lastAccessedDate":  "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "dateCreated":  "2019-05-23T10:05:41.663Z",
                        "projectEntitlements":  "",
                        "extensions":  "",
                        "groupAssignments":  ""
                    }
                ],
    "continuationToken":  "",
    "totalCount":  2 }
```

In CSV, I want Following Output:

```
id                                     principalName       licenseDisplayName    

4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d    abc@my.com         Basic
```

Comment: There is a bracket issue in this json.. secondly, you can use `Convertfrom-Json` to convert that and further convert it to csv using `Convertto-CSV` .. In an one liner `$jsondata | Convertfrom-json -depth 4 | convertto-csv | Out-file filepath\filename.txt -force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `Select-Object`, `Select-String` with a Regex pattern, and `ConvertTo-Csv`.

```
$j = @"
{
    "members":  [
                    {
                        "id":  "4b3556f1-df58-6c3c-848b-022fc6a8668d",
                        "user":  "@{subjectKind=user; metaType=member; domain=2161a74d-1c3e-4d34-a8c8-131360d2e92c; principalName=abc@my.com; mailAddress=abc.xyz@my.com; origin=aad; originId=bc20990e-cf30-4c37-9e4b-b04e37ab2b04; displayName=ABC; }",
                        "accessLevel":  "@{licensingSource=account; accountLicenseType=express; msdnLicenseType=none; licenseDisplayName=Basic; status=active; statusMessage=; assignmentSource=unknown}",
                        "lastAccessedDate":  "2019-05-23T05:54:25.14Z",
                        "dateCreated":  "2019-05-23T05:54:21.6Z",
                        "projectEntitlements":  "",
                        "extensions":  "",
                        "groupAssignments":  ""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":  "4c07118c-8dc0-4e85-97a5-5501003d620d",
                        "user":  "@{subjectKind=user; domain=2161a74d-1c3e-4d34-a8c8-131360d2e92c; principalName=xyz@gmail.com; mailAddress=xyz@gmail.com; origin=aad; originId=; displayName=xyz}",
                        "accessLevel":  "@{licensingSource=account; accountLicenseType=stakeholder; msdnLicenseType=none; licenseDisplayName=Stakeholder; status=pending; statusMessage=; assignmentSource=unknown}",
                        "lastAccessedDate":  "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "dateCreated":  "2019-05-23T10:05:41.663Z",
                        "projectEntitlements":  "",
                        "extensions":  "",
                        "groupAssignments":  ""
                    }
                ],
    "continuationToken":  "",
    "totalCount":  2 }
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$j.members | Select-Object id,
    @{n='principalName';e={($_.user | 
       Select-String "(?<=principalname=).*?(?=;)").matches.value}},
    @{n='licenseDisplayName';e={($_.accessLevel |
       Select-String "(?<=licenseDisplayName=).*?(?=;)").matches.value}} | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You can just remove the `| ConvertTo-Csv` if you want a tabular display in the console.

A somewhat alternative approach would be to remove the surrounding `@{}` from the property you want to access and then use `ConvertFrom-StringData` to return a hash table with sub-property values you can easily access.

```
$j.members | Select-Object id,
    @{n='principalName';e={($_.user -replace "^@{|}$" -split ';' |
        ConvertFrom-StringData).principalName}},
    @{n='licenseDisplayName';e={($_.accesslevel -replace "^@{|}$" -split ';' |
        ConvertFrom-StringData).licenseDisplayName}} |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Nice one (+1).With an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) you could save one replace  `-replace "^@{|}$"`

Comment: @LotPings, thank you for that suggestion. I have added it.

Comment: Thank you @AdminOfThings my issue is resolved. But another issue is while sending same csv through email. I have some issue.                                                  Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At line:35 char:8
+        $smtp.Send($message)
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

Comment: @PrashantPatwari the best thing to do is submit a new question for that issue